# Bootstrap Tooltips initialising but not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to set up Bootstrap Tool Tips and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<p>This is a <a href="#" title="A collection of words.">sentence</a> with a tooltip</p>​
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").tooltip();
});​
```

I have set up the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/)

The html appears to be transformed to the following:

```
<p>This is a <a href="#" data-original-title="A collection of words.">sentence</a> with a tooltip</p>
```

And the tooltip html is rendered:

```
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: -34px; left: 20.5px; display: block; "><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">A collection of words.</div></div>
```

With the correct CSS styles:

[image]

But it is never shown in the browser?

[image]

Comment: is it not possible to show it bottom by adding data-placement="bottom" ?

Comment: Good spot - the problem in the jsFiddle is that it is hidden by the iframe. Subtle difference between my production code and the jsFiddle..

Comment: Doh... FAIL! I will have a look into why this is not working on my production code, must be something else.

Comment: can you give link ?  or paste your code to check it

Comment: It's on an internal SharePoint, I will see if I can reproduce outside - thought I had it in jsFiddle, but it got me! Good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, it's just that in jsfiddle, everything outside the HTML box is hidden.

Updated version to show padding: http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/3/

Fred