# Bootstrap tooltip initialises but isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, laravel-mix

Before marking this question as a duplicate, I know there is one exact same question with the exact same problem but the solution isn't working for me. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172379/bootstrap-tooltips-initialising-but-not-showing) to that question.

The problem is, I know tooltips are being initialized because when I hover over my button, this markup shows up in my DOM.

```
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: -34px; left: 20.5px; display: block; "><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">Add Quotation.</div></div
```

But it isn't showing up in the browser! In case of inspect element, It shows me the exact tooltip but it isn't appearing. It's transparent! The JSfiddles and all are working but it's not working in just my code.

I am using **Laravel Mix** with **Vue.js**. Anything extra is to be done or I am missing something?

**UPDATE**: I have already added `data-toggle`, `data-placement` and `title` in my element on which I want a tooltip.

Comment: you need to add `data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left"`

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm shadow-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="View Quotation"><i class="mdi mdi-eye"></i></button> - I already did that @MerajKhan

Comment: Did you write js function `$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})`

Comment: Obviously! That's what I told in the question. It is being initialized! That's why tooltip code pops up in the DOM when I hover my element.

Comment: sometimes the problem was chrome cached my older js files.

Comment: I refreshed my JS files too!

Answer (score 2):

**Although we need additional information ...**

what you are describing is usually related to the parent position.
Try attaching the tooltip to the body when initializing it like so.

```
// AN EXAMPLE ELEMENT
<div class="tip" title="Some tooltip"></div>

// THE JQUERY
$('.tip').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
});
```

Let me know if this changes things and please add your initialization code
and the item your attaching the tooltip to css position

**Live Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sagive/aq9Laaew/137936/

Comment: Yes, replacing the default initialization code with the one you gave me changes some things. This time, It's not being initialized at all! It's not even creating a tooltip markup in DOM.

Comment: it was just an example.. this (edited my code) should work with your class (aka: tooltip)

Comment: I replaced the code you gave me (the second one) with the default one and gave "tooltip" class to the element. This time, My element went missing too! I mean it became transparent!

Comment: Your right.. this is wrong and i didnt notice this class="tooltip fade top in" - using the class tooltip is a problem... i would make a complete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! I am stuck at this simple thing since last many hours and I am totally frustrated!

Comment: No Problems... glad to help. if the div / span / whatever element your using to show a tooltip cant have the class tooltip as its the class used by bootstrap. try the example i added (and dont worry about it.. we will solve it in no time.)

Comment: Not being initialized at all! I mean it's not creating markup for a tooltip.

Comment: In js `animation: true` did you add?

Comment: Didn't get you @MerajKhan

Comment: @p01ymath $('.tip').tooltip({animation: true});

Comment: @MerajKhan with `tip` class, It's not being initialized at all! I think there is something wrong with my core.

Comment: @p01ymath `tip` class is example class you add your class.

Comment: Yes, I know that. @MerajKhan

Comment: it should work.. can you paste the div your trying to use to display tip? just paste your code in a comment so i could have a look.

Comment: Added a live example (see my answer)

Comment: Hi, I tried to execute the exact example you sent me. First, I replaced the default tooltip initialization code with the one you mentioned in the example. And then replaced my button with the `div` tag given in your example with exact class. In this case, It's not being initialized at all!

Comment: Did you see the example? ... try for the sake of debuggin to make a precise replica on your site - here you go again: https://jsfiddle.net/sagive/aq9Laaew/137936/

Comment: Yes. I saw the example. It is working on jsfiddle as I told you before. I tried to create an exact replica with the same div tag, same initialization code, and even the same CSS! But it's not being initialized at all except the default initialization code.

Comment: I also tried to use a vue-js package to create tooltips but It's showing the same behaviour.

Comment: Can u make sure your loading the bootstrap css file & js file of the latest version.. open chrome tools and make sure the css isnt 404'ing

Comment: @SagiveSEO , I just checked files. I have `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and ``bootstrap.min.css`. All of them are working perfectly and none of them are 404ing. However, I noticed very much strange behavior. In the first load, It does not initialize tooltips, in 2nd+ loads, It initializes tooltips but it isn't showing up.

Comment: SagiveSEO and @MerajKhan . Thanks for your help! I just solved the issue! The issue was not with the markup or initialization. But It was with JQuery Conflict. As I have mentioned, Laravel-mix includes jQuery out of the box and I was importing it from CDN too! Which created two jQuery instances or something like that. But once I removed the CDN one, Everything started working! Thanks again for your help!